# Windows service that runs a batch file

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have developed a Windows service which runs on Windows server. The purpose of the service is to run a batch file on local system which further runs a Java-based thread. The problem is that when I log in to server using remote session the service starts normally but both batch file and Java thread run in the background but when I log in to server without using remote session, i.e. going physically where the server is, then both Java thread and batch file window appears. My question is how can I prevent both batch file and Java thread running in the background when I log in to the server using remote session. The code which runs the batch file is appended below:

```
public void RunBatchFile()
        {
            while (!this.isStopped)
            {
                while (StartnStop)
                {
                    foreach (object element in apps)
                    {
                        App_arr chkapp = (App_arr)element;

                        System.DateTime now_date = System.DateTime.Now;
                        System.DateTime last_date = new System.DateTime(chkapp.last_time.Year, chkapp.last_time.Month, chkapp.last_time.Day, chkapp.last_time.Hour, chkapp.last_time.Minute, chkapp.last_time.Second);

                        System.TimeSpan time_span = now_date.Subtract(last_date);


                        if (time_span.Minutes >= chkapp.mins)
                        {
                          try
                            {
                                p = new Process();

                                string targetDir = string.Format(@chkapp.app_path.ToString().Substring(0, chkapp.app_path.ToString().LastIndexOf("\\")));
                                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
                                string batch_file_name = chkapp.app_path.ToString().Substring(chkapp.app_path.ToString().LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                                p.StartInfo.FileName = batch_file_name;

                                p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("C-Sharp CTF-Service Application");
                                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                                //p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                                p.Start();


                            }
                            catch (Win32Exception ex1)
                            {                              
                                log.WriteEntry(ex1.Message + "\n" + ex1.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                                sw.WriteLine(ex1.Message);
                                sw.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(40000);
                }
            }
            fs.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting that `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
` to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("C-Sharp CTF-Service Application");
 p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //Instead of false
 //Try this if above line doesn't work
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

**Note:**

If the [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username.aspx) and [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password.aspx) properties are not **Nothing**, the **CreateNoWindow** property value is ignored and a new window is created. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx))

Hope this works.